# Como abrir un archivo en el programa predeterminado desde C#?

Tags: c#, archivo

Es una pregunta muy general pero justo eso es lo que quiero, simplemente abrir un archivo del cual ya tenga la ruta en c# , no abrirlo en el form ni nada por el estilo, simplemente que al presionar un boton se abra el archivo en el programa predeterminado como si presionara enter

Comment: Revisate este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13755363) y este [otro](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38247311)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intenta utilizando [`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string filePath)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_) que ejecuta el archivo para abrir el programa asociado a su extension:

> Inicia un recurso de proceso al especificar el nombre de un documento o
>   archivo de aplicación y asocia el recurso con un nuevo componente de
>   Proceso.

Por ejemplo para abrir el notepad o programa asociado a abrir los archivos `.txt`:

```
Process.Start("c:/nota.txt");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo lo que necesitaba

Comment: En esta pregunta de SO viene un ejemplo con argumentos, espero te sirva: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365984/c-sharp-open-file-with-default-application-and-parameters